# PHP Flickr API - Retrieve Title from flickr.photosets.getInfo Response

Tags: php, arrays, flickr

I am getting the correct response from Flickr which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <photoset id="72157630469695108" owner="15823425@N00" primary="5110549866" secret="fd716fb5ee" server="1136" farm="2" photos="101" count_views="67" count_comments="0" count_photos="101" count_videos="0" can_comment="0" date_create="1341701808" date_update="1345054078">
    <title>Montana</title>
    <description />
  </photoset>
</rsp>
```

For some reason I can't get the title, I've tried the following:

```
$album_info = simplexml_load_file($album_info_xml); // this is what the response is stored in

echo $album_info['photoset']['title'];

foreach($album_info->photoset as $ps) {
    echo $ps['title'];
}
```

And a couple of other crazy things, I know it's something silly but don't know what it is I have missed.

Response can be seen here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getInfo

Just use `72157630469695108` as the set id or alternatively use this url: http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getInfo&api_key=7ccedd2c89ca10303394b8085541d9de&photoset_id=72157630469695108

Comment: Just to make sure, $album_info_xml contains a file name, not the actual xml string?

Comment: it's the url of the flickr api call, e.g. `$album_info_xml = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getInfo&api_key='.$api.'&photoset_id='.$set_id;`

Comment: Ok, have you checked the response with `print_r($album_info);`?

Comment: yes- it's above in the question, the response itself is fine, it's just I am not traversing the array correctly to get the value of the title field

Comment: The response in the question is the actual xml response as string, not the SimpleXmlElement object structure, that's why I asked. `print_r` should show how the resulting XML document looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SimpleXMLElement` directly, then `xpath` to find your node.

```
$album_info = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <photoset id="72157630469695108" owner="15823425@N00" primary="5110549866" secret="fd716fb5ee" server="1136" farm="2" photos="101" count_views="67" count_comments="0" count_photos="101" count_videos="0" can_comment="1" date_create="1341701808" date_update="1345054078">
    <title>Montana</title>
    <description />
  </photoset>
</rsp>'); // this is what the response is stored in

$result = $album_info->xpath('//title');

foreach ($result as $title)
{
  echo $title . "\n";
}
```

[Working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4pWjFH).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same position, this did the trick

```
$albumName = $album_info->photoset->title;
```